# Network from docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am running an experiment locally and I want to start one service that listen to a few ports, communicates with redis, and is externally accessible

```yml
version: "3.3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - office
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  workers:
    image: workers-image
    networks: 
      - office
    environment:
      NUM_WORKERS: 10
      REDIS_URI: 'redis://redis:6379'
    ports:
      - '15658-15680:15658-15680'
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

I was expecting to be able to access the `workers` service using e.g. `127.0.0.1:15660`, or, preferrably, something like `workers.office:15660`.

Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong?

### (Edit) What is not working

Sorry if after reading the original post it was not clear that what is not working as expected

After I start the `workers` service

```
docker-compose run -e NUM_WORKERS=10 workers
```

It will listen to a few different ports. Then I was expecting to be able to be able to get a response with

```
> curl 127.0.0.1:15660/metrics
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 15658: Connection refused
```

or

```
> curl workers.host:15658/metrics
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: workers.host
```

Comment: What isn't working right now? It's not clear from your question. Note that `120.0.0.1` is most likely an invalid address; maybe you meant `127.0.0.1` (which is the localhost address)?

Answer (score 0):

Docker `run` won't expose ports unless you pass  `--service-ports` to the command, e.g. `docker-compose run --service-ports -e NUM_WORKERS=10 workers`.

Also, the service-ports are created while building the container, so if you change the docker-compose file you have to run `docker compose build` again.